# Any ideas how to install 'ReachabilitySwift' for swift 3?

Tags: swift, swift3, cocoapods, reachability

I have tried to install :

```
 pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
```

into my Podfile, but I get this error:

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `ReachabilitySwift (~> 3)` required by `Podfile`

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `ReachabilitySwift (~> 3)`.

You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update`.
 * mistyped the name or version.
 * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.

Note: as of CocoaPods 1.0, `pod repo update` does not happen on `pod install` by default.

Any ideas how can I install it , I also tried manually, but it didn't work too.

P.S I am using CocoaPods

after updating:
CocoaPods 1.1.0.rc.2 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.1.0.rc.2

Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `SwiftyJSON` from `https://github.com/BaiduHiDeviOS/SwiftyJSON.git`, branch `swift3`
Downloading dependencies
Installing ReachabilitySwift 3 (was 2.3.3)
Using SVProgressHUD (2.0.3)
Installing SwiftyJSON 2.3.2 (was 2.3.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Pod installation complete! There are 3 dependencies from the Podfile and 3 total
pods installed.

[!] Your Podfile has had smart quotes sanitised. To avoid issues in the future, you should not use TextEdit for editing it. If you are not using TextEdit, you should turn off smart quotes in your editor of choice.
Ivans-Air-2:popo IvanDosevDimitrov$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run `sudo gem install cocoapods` and then `pod update`after that.

Comment: I got this message:
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories

Shall I wait more,because I got it 20min ago

Comment: Close the terminal and run it again, this can take a while though but not 20 mins...

Comment: Run `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`instead and then check all your frameworks and update them to the latest ones.